# Calculating geometry in longitude and latitude using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, geometry, coordinates

In ArcMap, I have some point features and I extract the coordinates in the attribute table

1. For Person 1 , I extract them in unit "metres"
2. For Persn 2, I extract them in unit "Decimal degree"
3. For the third, I extract them in "degree min sec"

After they bring in their editing back, I have to merge them. Should I do any conversion between them?

If so can you tell me the science behind them?

Comment: You should clarify what software you are working in and what specific problem you're having. what do you mean you're trying to merge them?

Comment: Are they capturing the information from the same shapefile and just want the coordinates in different formats?

Comment: What sort of editing are they doing? Are they moving the points? If so I would just recalculate the coordinates based on the new point location.

Comment: If you want to update the Geometry or Shape field you may run Make XY Event  Layer.

Comment: Are you saying that people will be editing the coordinates in the attribute table and then you will have to update the geometry itself with the new values? If so, why aren't they editing the geometries directly?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly. I think you will need to get the different points back to the same projection system. So, with the DMS and DD attributes bring them into ArcMap with a degree coordinate system. You will need to convert the DMS to DD.

Then you will need to bring in the metre coordinates into a new ArcMap Document and bring them in in metres.

Once you have these shapefile with a projection. Re project one to match the other. Then you can merge the two together.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me all the answers I need except for 1%

Comment: Great, if you need me to expand the answer let me know. Edit your question if there are any changes.

Comment: One more question, after I shortlist the items to DD and Metres, what coordinate system should I chose to project them. I use NZTM originally before I send out the files

Comment: I dont quite follow your request. Ultimately the coordinate system you hand over to your team is dependent on what they need. Once they give you the information back you create the XY Event layers in the same projection system that they are returning the information. So for the DD or DMS - WGS84 and for the metres - NZTM